# MEF and Wcf client proxy

Tags: wcf, mef

I'm wondering if it is possible to EXPORT an WCF client proxy to use IOC with MEF. And how to do that ?To make the wcf client proxy i used "add service reference". Any suggestions ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class is generated, you have two solutions :

1) you can edit the class and add the MEF export attribute, but it's not a good practice to modify generated classes

2) you can copy the generated class and create a new one with that, on which you have a total control and can add the MEF export attribute.

Comment: So there is no easyway of doing that what happens if i need to update the service reference then i have to recopy the class and so on.. Maybe there isn't any better solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You can create your own proxy, but it will based on the same interface than the service, so you always have to update it when the service is modified.

Answer (score 0):

The client class generated when you add the service reference is marked as Partial. Just create a second definition in a non-generated file and add the ExportAttribute to that.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/2011/10/using-wcf-services-in-prism-silverlight-applications/) is another solution. ... exposing the service functionality as a shared service.